# WPF - Access the parent Control from inside a Style Setter ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, styles, controltemplate, setter

When making controls non-amendable we display them as a `TextBox` to keep a consistent style. The problem is that a `ComboBox` can have any type of data so binding the `Text` property of the `ControlTemplate TextBox` is not as simple as using `SelectedItem`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}, Path=????, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ComboToTextConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The idea I have is to use a `Converter` and send the whole `ComboBox` so it can be handled by the `Converter` code. Is there anyway to do this?

Any other suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` properties:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="cStyle">
<Style.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
          <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource=
                   {RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                   Path=SelectedValue}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

and heres your `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox Name="cbox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        Style="{StaticResource cStyle}" 
        SelectedValuePath="SomeText" 
        DisplayMemberPath="SomeText" />
```

now when you set the `IsReadOnly` property to true on the `ComboBox`, it turns into a `TextBox` with the selected value as its text.